# Android | Google Drive | Display files in folder

Tags: java, android, google-drive-android-api

I've searched on Google but I don't find anything that can really help me.
I've tested some codes.

One test is this: [Get list of files from a specific folder in google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460799/get-list-of-files-from-a-specific-folder-in-google-drive) but it show only 3 files/folders (in         `// md gives you the file info`, I've added `md.getTitle()`) or nothing, I don't know why.

Then I've tried with this: https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/ListFilesInFolderActivity.java, changed the last method. I've used the `MetadataBufferResult result` so:

```
MetadataBuffer metadataBuffer = result.getMetadataBuffer();
Log.d("DRIVE","size: "+metadataBuffer.getCount());
metadataBuffer.release();
```

And the "size" is like the previus test: it is 3, 0 or 1, but there are more folder/files.

How can I list **all** files in a folder? Do you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to get all direct children of a particular folder, you can use `DriveFolder.listChildren` as discussed in [Working with Folders documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/folders#list_a_folders_contents).

However, to list all files of a specific folder, it would be better to use [**`Files: list`**](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) method with `q` parameter to filter your search as given in [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters). You can send a request with the following format:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q="'<FOLDER_ID>' in parents"
```

This sample request returns all files of the specified ID and also includes files with `trashed=true` in the results. Use the `trashed=false` query parameter to filter these from the results.

**Important Note:** Every request your application sends to the Drive API must include an authorization token as discussed in the [Drive API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth).

Here are some related SO posts which might also help:

- [Listing files and folders of GDrive using Google Drive Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153496/listing-files-and-folders-of-gdrive-using-google-drive-api)
- [Getting a list of files by folder on Drive SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400669/getting-a-list-of-files-by-folder-on-drive-sdk)

Comment: I've try with this https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list#try-it but what I can put in "q" field?